# Maven multimodule project not including profile depedencies in submodule war file

Tags: java, maven

So, I have a maven project that basically is something like this:

- module_parent

  - module_child_1 (jar)
  - module_child_2 (war)

module_parent.pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project ...>
<parent>
    <artifactId>test_module_dependencies</artifactId>
    <groupId>test_module_dependencies</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>module_parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>module_child_1</module>
    <module>module_child_2</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

module_child_1.pom:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>module_parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>test_module_dependencies</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>module_child_1</artifactId>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile1</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>dependency1</dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>profile2</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>dependency2</dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>  
</project>
```

module_child_2.pom:

```
<project ...>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>module_parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>test_module_dependencies</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <artifactId>module_child_2</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>test_module_dependencies</groupId>
            <artifactId>module_child_1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>crit-workflow</warName>
                    <webXml>WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

(I tried to shorten the code as much as possible).
So, module_child_2 is a WAR module. I want when doing a "mvn clean install -P profile1" to have in the target of module_child_2 a .war file. And I have it. The problem is that the dependencies in profile1 are not included in the .war file. I checked if the profile is actually loaded, using the maven-antrun-plugin with an , and I can confirm that it is loaded.

But the dependencies from module_child_1's profile1 are not included in the module_child_2.war archive.

NB If I put activeByDefault = true then the dependency1 library is included. But it's included even if the profile1 profile is not active.

Comment: What is the purpose of this alternative dependency? Maybe there is a simpler way to achieve what you want

Comment: It's actually a more complex project organized by submodules with inter-dependencies. I have 2 profiles: one that uses activemq and another that uses tibco mq. Depending on resource filtering and jndi lookups, a JMS infrastructure is constructed with either activemq or tibco, based on the selected profile.

Comment: I have some doubts on what you said? Firstly, You can run mvn clean install -P Profile1 only on a module1 project, because you have defined them there and seems strange that you can find the war file in a module2 target folder, then you should move profile in a parent pom an try from there to run the command

Comment: @Skizzo - the dependency is just for module1. That library is not used by any others. I can do -P profile1 on module_parent and everything works fine, it actually is loaded. The only thing is that in the war the module1 dependencies are not included. Why should I add in parent dependencies and profiles that are submodule specific?

Comment: Ok, but you have to consider that porject1 module has a jar packaging, then I think that it is not able to manage the dependencies (based on the configuration you've described above), then you should use a custom layout for your module1 project (using maven assembly plugin for example) and finally import it like dependency of the war